# rename files with one single command

Tags: linux, bash

I want to rename all files ( could be also one file ) under dir directory so each file under dir will added with the name “old_” before each file

Remark – I can do the rename with loop and mv each file to the new file name
But I prefer to do that with one command – is it possible?

when we need to rename one file is very simple

```
    mv dir/file  dir/old_file
```

but how to do the same when we have 100 files?

example

under dir I have

```
file1
file2
file3
```

what I want is

```
old_file1
old_file2
old_file3
```

OR

```
dse.txt
uytee.txt
drjf4.txt
```

convert to

```
old_dse.txt
old_uytee.txt
old_drjf4.txt
```

Comment: There's the `rename` command line tool which takes a perl expression such as `s/^/old_/` to apply to a number of files.

Comment: There are a myriad (well, several) questions on the subject — see the list of related questions on the right.  There's a Perl-based `prename` (sometimes installed as `rename`) that will do the job admirably.

Comment: can you give here real example ?  ( see my new update - file can be with diff name )